# Send email on saving the currency rates

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to send a notification email in acumatica when the currency rates for TODAY is saved?

We tried adding a automation notification for the Currency Rates screen trying all possible values in conditions, But it looks like the notification is not generated for this particular screen.

Comment: Just to make sure, are there pending emails in screen  SM507010 (Configuration > Email > Schedule > Send And Receive Email) ? Your email settings are correct ?

Comment: Yes. I tried the same with PO screen [from an answer you provided before] and it works. So settings should be correct. rite?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Automation Notifications can only be sent based on a change on the screen, rather than a change in the database, so that may be why you're not seeing the email send.

You could modify the Save action on the Currency Rate screen to send a notification whenever it's pressed.

I had to do something similar with PO's/Requisitions/Requests here:

[Sending notification to requester when PO is created in Acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011070/sending-notification-to-requester-when-po-is-created-in-acumatica)